# Correcting my output to match the expected

Tags: java

I am fairly new to coding and have been trying to do this assignment for hours. What I am trying to do is have my output look like the expected output but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Could someone please explain to me what it is I am doing wrong and guide me to the correct answer?
Thank You!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
 
public class ShowCharacter {
 
    public static void showCharacter(String s, int index) {
        System.out.println("The letter at position " + index + " is " + s.charAt(index));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        int index;
        System.out.println("Please enter a String");
        str = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the character's position");

        index = in.nextInt();
        while (true) {
            if(index >= 0 && index < str.length()) {
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Position. Enter a valid position");
            }
        }
        showCharacter(str, index);
    }
}
```

Input:
This is a sentence.
-7 -8 0

My output:
Please enter a String

Please enter the character's position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

etc. etc.

Expected output:

Please enter a String

Please enter the character's position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

Invalid Position. Enter a valid position

The letter at position 0 is T

Comment: Please format the desired and current output in a better way, so that we can help you

Comment: You might want to move the index input code into the while loop so that user can resubmit. Plus, check if the input string is not empty otherwise while loop is never going to break since index will not be less than str.length

Answer (score 1):

there is a simple solution for that.
First of all, your while loop runs the whole time on the same number (e.g -7) but you never change it, so it will always give you your error message.

You can solve this by reassigning index to a new input like this:

```java
while (true) {
  if(index >= 0 && index < str.length()) {
    break;
  } else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Position. Enter a valid position");
    index = in.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you so much. Turning the invalid message into an input never crossed my mind. I really appreciate the help CyberHD1811!!!\